# How to determine the position of the cursor in KeyDown event?

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I have override the KeyDown event and I need the position in the Text property of a textbox of the pressed Key. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the index is :

```
textbox1.CaretIndex
```

hope this is what you looking for